# Fixed Points and Sylow-Subgroups of Subgroups who are also Sylow-Subgroups of whole Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let a finite group $G$ act on a set $\Omega$. For some $\alpha \in \Omega$, denote by $G_{\alpha} = \{ g \in G : \alpha^g = \alpha \}$ the stabiliser of $\alpha$ in $G$. I want to show that:

(i) if $p$ is an odd prime dividing $G_{\alpha}$ and $P$ is a $p$-Sylow-subgroup of $G_{\alpha}$ which has at most two fixed points (i.e. elements $\alpha \in \Omega$ such that $\alpha^g = \alpha$ for all $g \in P$) then $P$ is a $p$-Sylow-subgroup of $G$.

I have some partial results, namely:

1) if $x \in G$ has exactly one fixed point (i.e. an element $\alpha$ with $\alpha^x = \alpha$), then $C_G(x) \le G$,

2) if $x \in G$ has exactly two fixed points $\alpha, \beta$, then every
element of odd order from $C_G(x)$ is contained in $G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}$.

But here I am stuck and do not know how to proceed... any help?

Comment: Since $p$ is odd and $g$ has at most $2$ fixed points, the size of the orbit of $\alpha$ under $G$ cannot be divisible by $p$, so the result follows from the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

Comment: the whole subgroup $P$ has at most two fixed points (i.e. at most two orbits under $P$ have length one), and because of $P \le G_{\alpha}$ one of them is $\alpha$. So how you conclude about orbits under $P$ about orbits under the whole group?

Comment: If $P$ has two fixed points, both in the orbit of $\alpha$ under $G$, then the size of that orbit is congruent to $2$ mod $p$. Otherwise, $\alpha$ is the only fixed point of $P$ in the orbit, so the size is congruent to $1$ mod $p$. Either way, it is not divisible by $p$.

Comment: but how do you know that that both fixed points lie in the orbit of $\alpha$ under $G$?

Comment: I don't - I considered the case when both of them lie in it and also the case when only one of them does. Please read what I wrote again.

Comment: Ok. I understand. You consider those cases and apply the finite $p$-group fixed point theorem with the action of $P$ on the orbit of $\alpha$ under $G$, to get that congruence mod p.